# Export coordinates from KML

Tags: google-maps, kml

I need export line coordinates from KML. I use some KML2CSV export tools. but this programs cant read my kml. Error: Read Error.

WHY i need coordinates:
I`v kml which there pipelines of regions. i must show this coordinates on google map without KML..

I hope that I can explain to yours.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your kml or a sample of KML that gives the error?  Not sure why you "must" do this without KML, maybe if you explained that, another solution might be possible.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8turl4ep465c5w/YAR_WSpipelines.kml -- kml link. for security i must do it. there will be secret materials. for it they want to do it without kml.

Comment: Google Maps is not the correct tool for protecting "secret" information.  FusionTables can keep the information somewhat protected (if you don't mind it being stored on Google's servers).

Answer (score 5):

**One solution: Google Fusion Tables**

One way to extract coordinates from your KML is to upload your KML to [Google's Fusion Tables](http://support.google.com/fusiontables).
If Google Earth parses your data then most likely you'll be able to import into a Fusion Table.

Short-cut to create a "Fusion Table" is simply clicking "Create a Fusion Table" from [here](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232) and pick your KML file. The direct way to create Fusion Table is login to Google Drive (aka Google Docs) then click "Create" and under "More" pick "Fusion Table" and import your KML file.

After it's imported you have lots of visualization options to try online.

You can also select "Download" under File menu and export the data back as a CSV or KML file.
http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2548807/

However, CSV export of KML import in Fusion Tables exports a KML geometry (not a separated latitude/longitude field) so you can further edit the resulting file in a text editor and strip off the KML markup.

```
1,"<Point><coordinates>-122.536226,37.86047,0.0</coordinates></Point>"
```

Google Fusion Tables also allows programmatic access through a RESTful [API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) with SQL-like queries to insert, update or delete rows of data.

UPDATE: Google Fusion tables will be retired in Dec 3, 2019 after which will no longer work.

**Validating KML**

If you're unable to use other KML2CSV converters then your KML probably has some invalid elements preventing it. Google Earth can still render badly formed KML so when you need to use that KML elsewhere you need to validate the KML data.

You can use the [Galdos KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm). Also suggest some [tips to validate your KML](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlBestPractice.html#KML_Validation_Tools).

Comment: ooo...Fusion table is a creat!!! But can i connect it with my MySQL DB? becouse i have data which users must modified it every day..

Comment: You do have the option to use the APIs to fetch or add data. http://developers.google.com/fusiontables

Answer (score 1):

This should help [here](http://www.landviser.net/content/extracting-geographical-lat-long-data-google-earth-kml-kmz-files-excel), you have to made a small change to your kml file: save it as a xml file, and then use excel to get what you want.

Comment: link shows blank page.