# how to get list of points from kml layer android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

i'm trying to get the coordinates of my kml layer in my android app, and i just cant seem to find how to do it.

i have this kml layer:

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, R.raw.allowedarea, getApplicationContext());
```

and i'm trying to get the Latitude and Longtitude list of his boundries points.

```
ArrayList<LatLnt> latlitArray = layer.soemthing();
```

could find anything, please guys help.

Comment: Post your kml file

Comment: Check this SO question [31166489](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166489/google-my-maps-how-can-i-export-coordinates-from-a-network-linked-kml-file?rq=1) and [13911205](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13911205/export-coordinates-from-kml) if it can help you :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39885632/1631285

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution

```
try {
        KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap, R.raw.zone, this);
        layer.addLayerToMap();

        Iterable<KmlContainer> containers = layer.getContainers();
        accessContainers(containers);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



public void accessContainers(Iterable<KmlContainer> containers) {
            for (KmlContainer container : containers) {
                if (container != null) {
                    if (container.hasContainers()) {
                        accessContainers(container.getContainers());
                    } else {
                        if (container.hasPlacemarks()) {
                            accessPlacemarks(container.getPlacemarks());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    public void accessPlacemarks(Iterable<KmlPlacemark> placemarks) {
        for (KmlPlacemark placemark : placemarks) {
            if (placemark != null) {
                KmlGeometry geometry = placemark.getGeometry();
                if (geometry instanceof KmlPolygon) {
                    KmlPolygon polygon = (KmlPolygon) geometry;
                    mLatLngList.addAll(polygon.getOuterBoundaryCoordinates());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

This will recursively access every placemark geometry inside the container. I'm not aware if the object obtained can actually be an instance of any other class or collection besides List and LatLng.

```
public void accessContainers(Iterable<KmlContainer> containers) {
    for(KmlContainer c : containers) {
        if(c.hasPlacemarks()) {
            for(KmlPlacemark p : c.getPlacemarks()) {
                KmlGeometry g = p.getGeometry();
                Object object = g.getGeometryObject();

                if(object instanceof LatLng) {
                    LatLng latlng = (LatLng)object;
                    //Do more stuff with the point
                }

                if(object instanceof List<?>) {
                    List<LatLng> list = (List<LatLng>)object;
                    //Do more stuff with the list of points
                }

                Log.d(TAG, g.getGeometryType() + ":" + object.toString());
            }
        }
        if(c.hasContainers()) {
            accessContainers(c.getContainers());
        }
    }
}
```